# Create sequence using rep() and seq()

Tags: r

I wanted to create this sequence here using rep() and seq() without using c( ):

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
nr_seq<-seq(3,30,3)
dr_seq<-seq(2,47,5)
nr_terms<-cumprod(nr_seq)
dr_terms<-cumprod(dr_seq)
req_terms<-nr_terms/dr_terms
1+req_terms

[1] 2.500000 2.285714 1.964286 1.680672 1.464095 1.309396 1.203041 1.131703
[9] 1.084666 1.054042
```

The sequence I have isn't the same as in the picture. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to add 1 but prepend one. So you need `c(1, req_terms)` not `1+req_terms`

Comment: @Julian_Hn Is there a way to avoid using c( ) or any explicit loops to do this?

Comment: Why would you need to avoid `c()`?

Comment: @Julian_Hn cuz I know how to do this with c( ). But how do we do this without using c( )? Also even with using c( ) although the number is correct it isn't displayed in fractions and such

Comment: Well of course it is not displayed in fractions ... You are requesting R to do numeric calculations. It does not know that the decimal numeric value it converts from its internal binary state is the result of this fraction. R does not display fractions anywhere. The only way would be to use strings in the representation and indicate the fraction with a `/` symbol

Comment: @Julian_Hn So is there a way to do this without using c( ) or this is the only way?

Comment: `cumprod(c(1, seq(3, 30, by=3) / seq(2, 47, by=5)))` or `n = 1:10; cumprod(c(1, 3*n / (2 + (n-1)*5)))`

Comment: @JesseLingLing There might be one. But you need to ask yourself the question why on earth you want to avoid the `c()`. If there isn't a good reason, why bother to waste time thinking about a solution?

Comment: Bro I am here practicing for my upcoming test in 3 days, and in the test there could be situations where they might restrict the use of c( ) for the obvious reason. So I don't want to use the c( ) cuz I already know that method.